# C# ShortBuffer implementation does not work right

Tags: java, c#, buffer

I am porting some code from [java](https://github.com/cytecbg/android-fskmodem/blob/992372da73d4595dd335c9da4eac3277cd2023e9/library/android.fskmodem/src/bg/cytec/android/fskmodem/FSKDecoder.java#L262) to C# (and no, I don't use Android, code just came from android library), which makes heavy use of Java.nio Buffers (ByteBuffer as well as ShortBuffer) (especialy functions like Remaining, Wrap, Put, Get, Rewind)
and since C# does not have theese 2 buffers, I decided to write my own

This is ByteBuffer implementation

```
using System;
using MePrograma.Exceptions;

namespace MePrograma.Tools.Buffers
{
    public class ByteBuffer
    {
        private byte[] buffer;
        private DataConverter c;
        private int capacity;
        private int index;
        private int limit;
        private int mark;
        private int offset;
        private bool readOnly = false;
        private ByteOrder order;

        public ByteBuffer ()
        {
            this.c = DataConverter.BigEndian;
        }

        protected ByteBuffer (byte[] buf, int start, int len)
        {
            this.buffer = buf;
            this.offset = 0;
            this.limit = start + len;
            this.index = start;
            //this.mark = start;
            this.mark = -1;
            this.capacity = buf.Length;
            this.c = DataConverter.BigEndian;
        }

        public static ByteBuffer Allocate (int size)
        {
            return new ByteBuffer (new byte[size], 0, size);
        }

        public static ByteBuffer AllocateDirect (int size)
        {
            return Allocate (size);
        }

        public byte[] Array ()
        {
            return buffer;
        }

        public int ArrayOffset ()
        {
            return offset;
        }

        public int Capacity ()
        {
            return capacity;
        }

        private void CheckGetLimit (int inc)
        {
            if ((index + inc) > limit) {
                throw new BufferUnderflowException ();
            }
        }

        private void CheckPutLimit (int inc)
        {
            if ((index + inc) > limit) {
                throw new BufferOverflowException ();
            }
        }

        public void Clear ()
        {
            index = offset;
            limit = offset + capacity;
            this.mark = -1;
        }

        public void Flip ()
        {
            if (!this.readOnly)
            {
                limit = index;
                index = offset;
                mark = -1;
            }
            else
                throw new ReadOnlyBufferException();
        }

        public byte Get ()
        {
            CheckGetLimit (1);
            return buffer[index++];
        }

        public byte Get(int i)
        {
            return buffer[i];
        }

        public void Get (byte[] data)
        {
            Get (data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        public void Get (byte[] data, int start, int len)
        {
            CheckGetLimit (len);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                data[i + start] = buffer[index++];
            }
        }

        public int GetInt ()
        {
            CheckGetLimit (4);
            int num = c.GetInt32 (buffer, index);
            index += 4;
            return num;
        }

        public short GetShort ()
        {
            CheckGetLimit (2);
            short num = c.GetInt16 (buffer, index);
            index += 2;
            return num;
        }

        public bool HasArray ()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public int Limit ()
        {
            return (limit - offset);
        }

        public void Limit (int newLimit)
        {
            limit = newLimit;
        }

        public void Mark ()
        {
            mark = index;
        }

        public void Order (ByteOrder order)
        {
            this.order = order;
            if (order == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) {
                c = DataConverter.BigEndian;
            } else {
                c = DataConverter.LittleEndian;
            }
        }

        protected ByteOrder GetOrder()
        {
            return this.order;
        }

        public int Position ()
        {
            return (index - offset);
        }

        public void Position (int pos)
        {
            if ((pos < offset) || (pos > limit)) {
                throw new BufferUnderflowException ();
            }
            index = pos + offset;
        }

        public void Put (byte[] data)
        {
            Put (data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        public void Put(ByteBuffer buf)
        {
            Put(buf.buffer, buf.ArrayOffset(), buf.Capacity());
        }

        public void Put (byte data)
        {
            if (!this.readOnly)
            {
                CheckPutLimit(1);
                buffer[index++] = data;
            }
            else
                throw new ReadOnlyBufferException();
        }

        public void Put (byte[] data, int start, int len)
        {
            if (!this.readOnly)
            {
                CheckPutLimit(len);
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    buffer[index++] = data[i + start];
                }
            }
            else
                throw new ReadOnlyBufferException();
        }

        public void PutInt (int i)
        {
            Put (c.GetBytes (i));
        }

        public void PutShort (short i)
        {
            Put (c.GetBytes (i));
        }

        public void PutLong(long i)
        {
            Put(c.GetBytes(i));
        }

        public void PutChar(char ch)
        {
            this.Put((byte)ch);
        }

        public int Remaining ()
        {
            return (limit - index);
        }

        public bool HasRemaining()
        {
            return Position() < Limit();
        }

        public void Reset ()
        {
            index = mark;
        }

        public void Rewind()
        {
            Position(0);
            mark = -1;
        }

        public void Compact()
        {
            limit = capacity;
            Position(Remaining());
            mark = -1;
        }

        public ByteBuffer Slice ()
        {
            ByteBuffer b = Wrap (buffer, index, buffer.Length - index);
            b.offset = index;
            b.limit = limit;
            b.order = order;
            b.c = c;
            b.capacity = limit - index;
            return b;
        }

        public static ByteBuffer Wrap (byte[] buf)
        {
            return new ByteBuffer (buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }

        public static ByteBuffer Wrap (byte[] buf, int start, int len)
        {
            return new ByteBuffer (buf, start, len);
        }

        public static ByteOrder NativeOrder()
        {
            // TODO: default win32 order
            return ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN;
        }

        public ByteBuffer Duplicate()
        {
            ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
            buf.buffer = new byte[this.buffer.Length];
            this.buffer.CopyTo(buf.buffer, 0);

            buf.c = this.c;
            buf.capacity = this.capacity;
            buf.index = this.index;
            buf.limit = this.limit;
            buf.mark = this.mark;
            buf.offset = this.offset;
            buf.order = this.order;
            return buf;
        }

        public ByteBuffer AsReadOnlyBuffer()
        {
            ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
            buf.buffer = new byte[this.buffer.Length];
            this.buffer.CopyTo(buf.buffer, 0);

            buf.c = this.c;
            buf.capacity = this.capacity;
            buf.index = this.index;
            buf.limit = this.limit;
            buf.mark = this.mark;
            buf.offset = this.offset;
            buf.order = this.order;
            buf.readOnly = true;
            return buf;
        }

        public LongBuffer AsLongBuffer()
        {
            LongBuffer buf = new LongBuffer();
            buf.buffer = new byte[this.buffer.Length];
            this.buffer.CopyTo(buf.buffer, 0);

            buf.c = this.c;
            buf.capacity = this.capacity;
            buf.index = this.index;
            buf.limit = this.limit;
            buf.mark = this.mark;
            buf.offset = this.offset;
            buf.order = this.order;
            return buf;
        }

        public ShortBuffer AsShortBuffer()
        {
            ShortBuffer buf = new ShortBuffer();
            buf.buffer = new byte[this.buffer.Length];
            this.buffer.CopyTo(buf.buffer, 0);

            buf.c = this.c;
            buf.capacity = this.capacity;
            buf.index = this.index;
            buf.limit = this.limit;
            buf.mark = this.mark;
            buf.offset = this.offset;
            buf.order = this.order;
            return buf;
        }

        public IntBuffer AsIntBuffer()
        {
            IntBuffer buf = new IntBuffer();
            buf.buffer = new byte[this.buffer.Length];
            this.buffer.CopyTo(buf.buffer, 0);

            buf.c = this.c;
            buf.capacity = this.capacity;
            buf.index = this.index;
            buf.limit = this.limit;
            buf.mark = this.mark;
            buf.offset = this.offset;
            buf.order = this.order;
            return buf;
        }

        public int GetMark() { return this.mark; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string summarizing the state of this buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> A summary string </returns>
        public override String ToString()
        {
            return ($@"{GetType().Name}[pos={this.Position()} lim={this.Limit()} cap={this.Capacity()}]");
        }
    }
}
```

ByteOrder is just an enum

```
public enum ByteOrder
{
    BIG_ENDIAN,
    LITTLE_ENDIAN
}
```

DataConverters class is to big for this question so you can get it [here](https://hastebin.com/share/anekuvugot.kotlin)

Exeptions are nothing fancy, just extending System.Exeption class so I can define my own exeption like this

```
    public class BufferOverflowException : System.Exception
{
    public BufferOverflowException() : base()
    {
    }

    public BufferOverflowException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public BufferOverflowException(System.Exception e)
        : this("", e)
    {
    }

    public BufferOverflowException(string message, System.Exception exception)
        : base(message, exception)
    {
    }
}
```

and this is my ShortBuffer implementation

```
using System;

namespace MePrograma.Tools.Buffers
{
    public class ShortBuffer : ByteBuffer
    {
        public new static ShortBuffer Allocate(int size)
        {
            return new ShortBuffer(new byte[size * 2], 0, size * 2);
        }
        public static ShortBuffer Wrap(short[] data)
        {
            ShortBuffer buf = new ShortBuffer(new byte[data.Length * 2], 0, data.Length * 2);
            buf.Put(data);
            // Set the limit to the actual data length
            buf.Limit(data.Length * 2);
            return buf;
        }

        public ShortBuffer() { }

        protected ShortBuffer(byte[] buf, int start, int len)
            :base(buf, start, len)
        {
        }

        public void Put(short val)
        {
            this.PutShort(val);
        }

        public void Put(short[] data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                this.PutShort(data[i]);
            }
        }

        public ShortBuffer Put(int index, short s)
        {
            // Check the bounds
            if (index < 0 || index + 2 > Limit())
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            // Convert the short to bytes and put them in the buffer
            byte[] shortBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(s);
            if (base.GetOrder() == ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
            {
                // If the order is little endian, reverse the byte order
                System.Array.Reverse(shortBytes);
            }

            // Put the bytes in the buffer at the specified index
            System.Array.Copy(shortBytes, 0, Array(), ArrayOffset() + index, 2);

            return this;
        }

        public new int Position()
        {
            return base.Position() / 2;
        }

        public new short[] Array()
        {
            int remaining = Remaining() / 2;
            short[] shortArray = new short[remaining];

            for (int i = 0; i < remaining; i++)
            {
                shortArray[i] = GetShort();
            }

            return shortArray;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string summarizing the state of this buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> A summary string </returns>
        public override String ToString()
        {
            return ($@"{GetType().Name}[pos={this.Position()} lim={this.Limit()} cap={this.Capacity()}]");
        }
    }
}
```

Now ByteBuffer class works fine (at least my tests showed that)
but ShortBuffer behaves odly

Here is my test for it (C#)

```
// Declare and initialize the byte array 
short[] bbb = { 10, 20, 30 };

// print the byte array length 
Console.WriteLine("Array length : "
                   + bbb.Length);

// print the byte array element 
Console.WriteLine("\nArray element : "
                  + "[" + string.Join(", ", bbb) + "]");

// wrap the short array into shortBuffer 
// using wrap() method 
ShortBuffer shortBuffer = ShortBuffer.Wrap(bbb);

// Rewind the ByteBuffer 
shortBuffer.Rewind();

// print the byte buffer 
Console.WriteLine("\nshortBuffer : "
                   + "[" + string.Join(", ", shortBuffer.Array()) + "]");

//Add 15 between 10 and 30
//shortBuffer.Put(1, (short)15);

// print the byte buffer 
//Console.WriteLine("\nshortBuffer with replaced number : "
//                   + "[" + string.Join(", ", shortBuffer.Array()) + "]");

// print the ByteBuffer capacity 
Console.WriteLine("\nshortBuffer capacity : "
                   + shortBuffer.Capacity());

// print the ByteBuffer position 
Console.WriteLine("\nshortBuffer position:  "
                   + shortBuffer.Position());

//Is space left
Console.WriteLine("\nhasRemaining:  "
                   + shortBuffer.HasRemaining());

// print the remaining position 
Console.WriteLine("\nRemaining:  "
                   + shortBuffer.Remaining());

//Set position to 3
shortBuffer.Position(3);
Console.WriteLine("New position set to 3");

//Is space left
Console.WriteLine("\nhasRemaining:  "
                   + shortBuffer.HasRemaining());

// print the remaining position 
Console.WriteLine("\nRemaining:  "
                   + shortBuffer.Remaining());
```

and here is my test in Java (its almost the same as C# one)

```
// Declare and initialize the byte array 
short[] bbb = { 10, 20, 30 }; 

// print the byte array length 
System.out.println("Array length : "
                   + bbb.length); 

// print the byte array element 
System.out.println("\nArray element : "
                   + Arrays.toString(bbb)); 

// wrap the short array into shortBuffer 
// using wrap() method 
ShortBuffer byteBuffer = ShortBuffer.wrap(bbb); 

// Rewind the ByteBuffer 
byteBuffer.rewind(); 

// print the byte buffer 
System.out.println("\nshortBuffer : "
                   + Arrays.toString(byteBuffer.array())); 

//Add 15 between 10 and 30
byteBuffer.put(1, (short)15);

// print the byte buffer 
System.out.println("\nshortBuffer with replaced number : "
                   + Arrays.toString(byteBuffer.array())); 

// print the ByteBuffer capacity 
System.out.println("\nshortBuffer capacity : "
                   + byteBuffer.capacity()); 

// print the ByteBuffer position 
System.out.println("\nshortBuffer position:  "
                   + byteBuffer.position()); 

//Is space left
System.out.println("\nhasRemaining:  "
                   + byteBuffer.hasRemaining()); 

// print the remaining position 
System.out.println("\nRemaining:  "
                   + byteBuffer.remaining()); 

//Set position to 3
byteBuffer.position(3);
System.out.println("New position set to 3");

//Is space left
System.out.println("\nhasRemaining:  "
                   + byteBuffer.hasRemaining()); 

// print the remaining position 
System.out.println("\nRemaining:  "
                   + byteBuffer.remaining());
```

If I run this test from java, I get this

```
Array length : 3

Array element : [10, 20, 30]

shortBuffer : [10, 20, 30]

shortBuffer with replaced number : [10, 15, 30]

shortBuffer capacity : 3

shortBuffer position:  0

hasRemaining:  true

Remaining:  3
New position set to 3

hasRemaining:  false

Remaining:  0
```

But if I run this from C# (my buffer reimplementation) I get this (I had to comment out the **shortBuffer.Put(1, (short)15);**, because due to the wierd buffer that gets created, I only get Destination array was not long enough exeption)

```
Array length : 3

Array element : [10, 20, 30]

shortBuffer : [10, 20, 30]

shortBuffer capacity : 6

shortBuffer position:  3

hasRemaining:  False

Remaining:  0
New position set to 3

hasRemaining:  True

Remaining:  3
```

I did test **shortBuffer.Put(1, (short)15);** separatly like this

```
ShortBuffer bbb = ShortBuffer.Allocate(3);

//Fill buffer with numbers
bbb.Put((short)10);
bbb.Put((short)20);
bbb.Put((short)30);

//Add 15 between 10 and 30
bbb.Put(1, (short)15);

Console.WriteLine("\nArray element : "
                 + "[" + string.Join(", ", bbb.Array()) + "]");
```

But something is realy wrong with my Put method, because nothing is ever put inside the buffer

I am realy confused, why does the ByteBuffer work fine, while the ShortBuffer does not?

Hope someone has a sharper eyes then I do and could maybe found out what the problem is

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards